# Why are constraints different for different devices of same size class?

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I have a problem with constraints that I can't understand. The size class that I choose is "wCompact, hRegular", to work for all iPhone devices in Portrait mode. After Setting a trailing constraint for the label "SourceLbl", the distance between that and the right edge was different for different devices.But Why are they different? I want the constraints to be the same for devices of the same size class.

[image: Snapshot1]

[image: Snapshot2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have no constraints for the 'UITableView' and that's why it's being cut on smaller device screens.

Answer (score 0):

set `top,bottom,leading and trailing` constraints to your `tableview`. so it will resize according to device size.